# How to Style @Html.BeginForm() using Razor and VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html, razor

I have done plenty of searching the web for an answer and cant seem to break through. I am trying to set the maximum height for the message box text area at the bottom of the form. I am using VB.Net, MVC and Razor to try and accomplish this. If I was in C# I would know how to write it out but I guess I dont have enough of an understanding of that to translate to VB. The company I work for uses VB but no one uses MVC so I am on my own here.

The Code:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm())
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @<div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Notification</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})

                @*<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.DateStart, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.DateStart, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.DateStart, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>*@

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.DateEnd, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.DateEnd, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.DateEnd, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Title, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Title, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.Class = "form-control datepicker"}})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Title, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Message, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Message, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Message, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        End Using
```

atempt at adding a class and styling

```
<div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Message, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Message, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control newClass"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Message, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS

```
.newClass {
    min-height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Add an additional class name and style it with css, or add the `rows` attribute assuming its generating a `<textarea>`

Comment: check the main post for what I did

Comment: I did the css styling with a class and restarted visual studio and it worked haha thanks for the help

Comment: Probably because the style sheet was cached - you would have just needed to refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new CSS class and use that for your text area.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Message, 
             New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control myFixedWidth"}})
```

And the CSS

```
.myFixedWidth
{
  height: 250px;
  //Customize the way you want
}
```

`@Html.EditorFor` will render text area if you have `DataType.MultilineText` text decoration on your property name.

```
Public Class RegisterEventVM

    <DataType(DataType.MultilineText)> _
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set
            m_Name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String

End Class
```

If you do not want to decorate your viewmodel property with this attribute, you may use the `Html.TextAreaFor` helper method to render the text area.

Comment: ive tried something very similiar. see my edit on the main post, it doesnt work. no console errors.

Comment: dude i dont know what happened, i restarted visual studio trying the same thing and it worked! thanks for trying though